# Is it possible to use the same coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, androidx, coroutine

I need to do some treatment in a I/O Thread.
Is it possible to always use the same Coroutine, maybe with a Tag or something?

Comment: Posted an answer, but not sure if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-use the coroutines by simply creating it first and then using it

```kotlin
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
scope.launch { 
     // somthing in io
}
 // somewhere else
scope.launch { 
     // somthing else in io
}
```

Comment: What if I leave this file, finish the treatment done in this coroutine, do something else and then call back this file. Will I use the same coroutine?

Comment: Keep the variable in a shared state where it's needed. For example if you are using it in two separate functions in a class, add this a class property.

Comment: As a global property you mean? I declare it outside a function, right?

Comment: Yes. It should be somewhere that it does not get recreated when you don't want it to.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're talking about reusing a CoroutineScope, not a coroutine. On Android, you usually never actually call the CoroutineScope constructor because the framework already provides you with scopes that are tied to lifecycles.

Answer (score 1):

If you literally mean you want to reuse a coroutine, the coroutine itself is defined by a suspend function with a single CoroutineScope receiver parameter.

```
val myCoroutine: suspend CoroutineScope.()->Unit = {
    // do stuff
}
```

Then to use it repeatedly, you can pass the instance to the launch function:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(block = myCoroutine)
```

If it has to return something, you would use it with `async` instead:

```
val myCoroutine: suspend CoroutineScope.()->Int = {
    // do stuff
    Random.nextInt(10)
}

val deferred = lifecycleScope.async(block = myCoroutine)
```

I'm not sure why you would do any of the above, though, because it's simpler to write a regular suspend function that you reuse:

```
suspend fun doSomething() {
    delay(100)
    println("Hello world")
}

//...

lifecycleScope.launch {
    doSomething()
}
```